# Java GridBadLayout positioning

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I would be grateful for any help/suggestion regarding my problem. I attached the image of my simple program which shows that the positioning of the components seems a bit off. My question is - why the ComboBox `From...` as well as TextField `Enter value here...` start so far off of the left corner? I've given `gridx=0` so it positions the component on the very edge of the window, but components start some pixels off from the edge. How can I fix it?
Also, what do I need to do/consider to remove dependency of the rows on each other? I mean how to position components anywhere I want in one row without effecting the position of other components in another row. Thank you!
Piece of Code:

```
    JPanel container = new JPanel();
    container.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    getContentPane().add(container, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    TitledBorder outputCenter;
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    label = new JLabel("Choose measure system to convert");
    label.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridwidth = 2; 
    c.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 20, 0);
    container.add(label, c);

    fromList = new JComboBox<String>(convertFrom); 
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.gridwidth =1; 
    c.ipadx = 20; 
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START; 
    container.add(fromList, c);

    toList = new JComboBox<String>(convertTo);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.ipadx = 20;
    container.add(toList, c);

    //Field where user enters the value to be converted
    input = new JTextField("Enter value here...");
    input.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,30));;
    input.setEditable(true);
    input.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    input.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    input.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            input.setText("");}});
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.gridwidth = 1; 
    c.ipady = 20;
    container.add(input, c);

    //The area where the output/result is shown
    output = new JTextArea(10,30);
    output.setEditable(false);
    output.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
    output.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    outputCenter = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK), "Output");
    outputCenter.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.CENTER);
    output.setBorder(outputCenter);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.insets = new Insets(50,5,10,10);
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    container.add(output, c);

    //Convert button
    convert = new JButton("Convert");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 3;
    c.ipadx = 50; 
    container.add(convert, c);
}
```

Output:[image: Output]

Comment: Possibly due to `c.ipadx = 20;` - remember, when using `GridBagConstraints`, `GridBagLayout` will take a copy, but if you keep using it, it will continue with the previous values. Try resetting `c.ipadx` to `0`

Comment: @MadProgrammer, no ipadx just gives extra width, making the component bigger, doesn't effect the positioning. I tried to set it to 0, but no luck.

Comment: If the component is aligned to the right, ipadX will effect the position x position of subsequent rows in that column, as the components continue to be laid

Comment: @MadProgrammer, how should I align it to the left though?

Comment: The "from" field is been laid out off to the left because of layout requirements imposed on by the both the constraints applied to itself and the constraints of the text field

Comment: There are many ways you "might" fix it. You could use `c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;` instead of `LINE_START` for example.  A better solution might to be place both combo boxes into their own container and layout the container instead

Comment: (1-) `I've given gridx=0 so it positions the component on the very edge of the window,`  - The components will automatically be centered in the panel unless you have one of the components take up the extra space. You were given a link to the tutorial on how to use the GridBagLayout in your last question. Read the tutorial!!!  The tutorial will tell you which constraint you need to use. Or instead of playing with the GridBagConstraints you can use a wrapper panel. For example a FlowLayout will display components at their preferred size left aligned.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, `GridBagLayout` is a "flexible grid" layout manager.  It still relies on the concept of rows and columns, but each row and column has it's own size, based on the requirements of the components and the constraints applied to them.

This means, that you combo box is been aligned to the left position because of a combination of `c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START` and the space requirements of the `JTextField` sharing the same column.

You "could" change `c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START` to `c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END`, while will (in your case) align the combo box to the right edge of the column, for example...

[image: Possible solution]

Another solution would be to use a combination of containers to reduce the overall complexity of the layout.  For example, you could add both the combo boxes to their own container, managing the layout requirements for them in an isolated manner and then layout that container within the large scheme of things

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer. If I got your right, you mean to create another JPanel and add comboboxes into it?

Comment: Essentially, yes.  You could also do it for "other" parts of the UI where a relationship exits between two components, but which (when grouped) together generates another relationship to other components in the layout.  It's a great way to reduce the overall complexity of the layouts